# Sharing files between dockers using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to understand the best approach in the following example:

- I have 10 git projects. Each project has its own Dockerfile
- I have a git project that has a docker-compose file and references the other 10 git projects.
- I have a large file that needs to be used in each Dockerfile.
- I would like to place that large file in 1 location and have each Dockerfile reference it (vs commit that large file in each git project)

Is it possible to save this file in the git project that has the docker-compose file and pass this file to each docker instance using docker-compose? Or does manual copying have to be done in this type of scenario?

I've tried the following but to no avail:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  docker-compose-project:
    ...blah

  some-docker-project:
    ...blah
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/<path-to-file>/some.file
        target: /data/some.file
```

I can run `ls -la /home/<path-to-file>/some.file` and confirm it exists.

Then in some-docker-project's Dockerfile I'd have a line like

```
    RUN ls -la /data
```

Results in

```
ls: cannot access '/data': No such file or directory
```

FWIW I seem to get the same issue when doing a volume mount instead of bind (both as the file and as its parent folder). Also, I do not see a mount for this when using `RUN df -aTh`

Comment: What is the file; can you just have one copy of it, and have the other projects make a network call to the service that has it?  How large is it?  What is a "git project" in this context, and can you use your language-native dependency system (npm, Bundler, pip, ...)?

Comment: It would be a proprietary file that really only needs one copy and would be stored in the docker-compose project. I looked into volumes/bind mounts but can't get it to see it

Comment: Dockerfiles can never see volume mounts of any sort, or anything else outside the immediate `build:` block in a `docker-compose.yml` file.  If you need the file during the build process, you have to `COPY` it in (or build your image `FROM` a base image that includes it).

Comment: But that still begs the question of how to COPY it from a non-local project? I thought that is what mounts/volumes are for